# Is the mapping class group of $\Bbb{CP}^n$ known?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, mapping-class-groups

In his paper ["Concordance spaces, higher simple homotopy theory, and applications"](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/ConcordanceSpaces.pdf), Hatcher calcuates the smooth, PL, and topological mapping class groups of the $n$-torus $T^n$. This requires an understanding of the surgery structure set of the $n$-torus, as well as the space of self-equivalences (easy, because the torus is aspherical and a Lie group).

At least $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ of $\text{hAut}(\Bbb{CP}^n)$, the space of self-homotopy equivalences, are known: the former is $\Bbb Z/2$ because $[\Bbb{CP}^n, \Bbb{CP}^n] = [\Bbb{CP}^n, \Bbb{CP}^\infty] = \Bbb Z$, and the only invertible elements are $\pm 1$; further the homology of this space seems to have been calculated by Sasao, who gives that $\pi_1 \text{hAut} = \Bbb Z/(n+1)$.

The best references I know for the surgery structure set of $\Bbb{CP}^n$ are Wall's book on surgery and the Madsen-Milgram book on Top/PL cobordism groups "The classifying spaces for surgery and
cobordism of manifolds", neither of which seem to give a completely explicit description.

From this, it's not immediately clear to me whether enough is known to run Hatcher's argument for $T^n$ on complex projective space.

Has anybody computed the various mapping class groups of $\Bbb{CP}^n$ when $n \geq 3$? Maybe in any specific examples, or when $n$ is very large? If not, is it out of reach with current technology?

(I would also be interested in other infinite families of high-dimensional manifolds, like real projective spaces and lens spaces, but I imagine those require strictly more work to understand, given the presence of non-trivial fundamental group without being aspherical like the torus is.)

Comment: There are spectral sequences developed by Schultz, and Becker-Schultz that converge to homotopy groups of the identity component of the space of self-maps of $CP^n$. See section 6 in https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4874 and references therein. The computational difficulties are substantial, e.g., in the linked paper we only manage to get partial information on $\pi_7$.

Comment: Only small homotopy groups seem relevant in Hatcher's computation, though, so I hope that doesn't cause too much trouble. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Kreck and Su have announced a paper containing the case n=3, see Remark 1.4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05693. You could try asking one of them.

Comment: @skupers Kreck points out to me that the oriented smooth mapping class group $\pi_0 \text{Diff}^+(\Bbb{CP}^3)$ was calculated by [Brumfiel](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02566851) to be $\Bbb Z/4$, all of whose elements are represnted by diffeomorphisms supported in a ball. I did not check but presumably $\pi_0 \text{Diff}$ is the dihedral group on 8 elements.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of that paper!

Comment: Regarding your last comment: Wall (MR0156354, MR0177421) and Kreck (MR0561244) have computed various mapping class groups of highly connected manifolds up to extension problems.